# Excel VBA Error 1004 - This action won't work on multiple selections (need to copy and paste empty columns)

Tags: excel, vba

I've looked around at previous error codes and haven't found anything that satisfies what I am looking for. I am looking to import a region of data from another Excel Workbook into the existing Workbook so I can automate some data cleansing procedures. I have a little bit of programming experience and am following a Udemy course on Excel VBA so most of the code has come from there.

So far, I get the open dialog working, select my new workbook, highlight the region and store the address of said region, then highlight the same region and copy all data, then reopen my original workbook and copy the data into the region's address. When I step through the code and reopen the first workbook it has the correct cell range highlighted but fails to paste - The error dialog is below. I think the reason is because I have columns that have zero data in them other than a title bar.

**Edit:** My dataset has 24 columns (A through X) with a heading on Row 1 in each cell - A1, through X1 have data in them and is therefore treating this as the X dimensions of the `CurrentRegion`. I have 232 (but otherwise *n*) rows, but columns F, P, R, U and V are empty cells from 2nd row to 232nd row, but I wish to retain their position and headings. In removing these columns my code works, but I wish to carry them across **exactly as they are**. This means that somewhere, `CurrentRegion` is seeing these 'empty columns' as separate regions and not including them, when I want them to be included.

[image: Error code and Dialog Window]

My original code was just to paste into Cell A1 without storing the Cell Range as a variable, and this yielded the same error code. I know the Cell Range method is working as the Cell Range is highlighted but as the error says, there is clearly an issue with highlighting the data. I have also cleared my clipboard to ensure there's nothing spurious going on. The final step was to remove the columns that had no data in them in the file I wish to import and that seemed to work, however I need these columns. Code below;

```
Option Explicit

Sub ImportFile()
Dim FileToOpen As Variant
Dim OpenBook As Workbook
'Dim CellRange As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your File", FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*xls*")

If FileToOpen <> False Then
    Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)

    'CellRange = OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address
    OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy

    'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ImportedFile").Range(CellRange).PasteSpecial xlValues
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ImportedFile").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlValues

    OpenBook.Close False
    
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I suppose my questions are:

1. Is there a way to import the data from the other file, including empty columns without treating it as 'separate regions'?
2. should I delete these columns using VBA prior to the copy and put them back in after the data import (paste)?

Just for clarity, it is not viable to have a user delete these columns before importing, and I have no way to exclude these columns from being created from our CRM as it's not easily customizable.

Thank you so so much in advance - this truly is a wonderful resource and I am very grateful for the help.

Comment: `CurrentRegion` goes to the next empty column/row and do not include them, if somehow there are cells linking them. Forget about your code and please, try better describing what are you trying to do. Do you try copying all the sheet content (empty columns included)? If yes, try `UsedRange` instead of `CurrentRegion`.

Comment: I have added additional information in the **Edit** section regarding the structure of my data. I can't share what it looks like due to confidentiality, however I will give UsedRange a go now and see if this works. Thank you.

Comment: First step is debugging your code and check which line is throwing error.

Comment: Do all columns in a specific worksheet have the same number of rows?

Comment: @FaneDuru - No, rows can be of *n* length, meaning any number.  On average anywhere from 2 to 2000, however 5 of the columns will be empty **except** for the headers (row 1). This is where `CurrentRegion` is failing me, because if I remove these columns, it works fine, but I want to keep these columns.

Comment: Did you try my suggestion? It is a matter of 2 seconds modification...

Comment: @FaneDuru - Yes, I get `Run-Time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method` when using this in place of `CurrentRegion` for the copy, or `OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").UsedRange.Copy`. When removing the Range and using just `UsedRange`, I get the same Error Code as above, `1004: action won't work on multiple selections.`. The code looks like `OpenBook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy`

Comment: Not in this way... Please, try: `OpenBook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy`

Comment: @FaneDuru - This still gives me the same error code: `1004: This action won't work on multiple selections.` I can either post a censored version of my data to better describe what I am trying to achieve or just come up with a different workaround.

Comment: Strange... Please, try sharing a dummy workbook, if possible. Bifore that, try ne next way, please: `Dim arr As Variant` then `arr = OpenBook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Value` followed by `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ImportedFile").Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arr), UBound(arr, 2)).Value = arr`. The array way is the fastest, anyhow. Since you do not need format, it looks to be the most appropriate. Of course, you should comment the previous lines involved in copying...

Comment: @FaneDuru - THAT WORKED! Thank you!!! I have also copied a sample of data in Google Sheets. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pYps4ZoXcKdRb4AlSqzWrFZ1YmsbUTPh15XaR5CL8Ro/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Glad I could help! No time now to check the shared workbook... Anyhow, the array method is the fastest one... It does not use the clipboard. It input all the range in an array (no matter of any emptiness) and put it in the place to be copied. But the size of the place must be identic to the array one...